# Adding different collapse menu in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using two or more diferent menu, the problem i have is that, second collapse open together with down toggle??

Here is HTML

```
<footer>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-second">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a> </p>
      </div>
       <div class="navbar-collapse-second collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:red;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> COPYRIGHT </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
```

And here is CSS

```
            footer > nav > div.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
footer > nav > div.navbar-header > button {
    display: block;
}
footer > nav > div.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
footer > nav > div.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
footer > nav > div.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
footer > nav > div.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
footer > nav > div..navbar-nav>li>a {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Is i possible to add several button on collapse??

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/h2scz3q5/

Try to click on bootom navigation, top navigation opens with bootom, and when try to click on brand in bootom, something strane is happening, first collapse at bootom is not closing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the Unique target

In button

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse1"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
```

Target div

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse1 collapse">
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-second">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse1"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse1 collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a> </p>
      </div>
       <div class="navbar-collapse-second collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text"> <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:red;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"> COPYRIGHT </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2scz3q5/1/)

Comment: Nice, fixed, is it possible in that colapse load external file?

Comment: sorry can't understand , can you explain in detail

Comment: You can add to modal like this TML

1

<a data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>

Comment: Is it possible to add to collapse like this  TML

1

<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-second"href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target=".navbar-collapse-second collapsl">Click me !</a>

Comment: like this you can use:  <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle overlay-display" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse1">Click me! </a>

Comment: If you use href="fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/"  , the page will redirect to another page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60383/discussion-between-gorostas-and-jake745).